# Mysql store things like "Facebook likes"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have to create a like system (the name won't be "like", Facebook owns it).
So I imagined two ways to store these likes in my database and I want to know, which way is the better for a very high-traffic site.

1. Create table comment_likes with "id", "comment_id", "user_id" cells. In comments table store the "like_count", so I don't need to count it when I need to write it out. But likes are easy to do thing, so people will create a lots of them and if I need to list a specified comment's likes, I need to read the whole comment_likes table and found all the user_ids. This could be millions of rows in the future. If 1000 user will do it in the same time, my system will die.
2. My second thought was, to store likes in comments table. create a cell named "likes" with a list of user_ids like this: 1#34#21#56#....
   So when somebody like/unlike a comment just CONCAT or REPLACE his/her id in this cell with a #. When I need to list specified comment just explode this list at #-s.

I think 2nd could be faster and smarter, but what do you think about this?

Comment: The second approach will run into issues - what if the column you've created is too small to store all the data? Additionally, you can only search it using queries with LIKE, which means it'll be slower, as indexing won't work. The first option will produce more rows, but with indexing, it'll be much, much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is much better, because you have the benefits of a relational setup. For example: What if you want to get the comments from the database userId x has liked? With the first setup this is a fast and simple query. In the second case you would have to use a LIKE, which is much slower and inaccurate. (Imagine the userId is 1, and the likes field in the comments table contains #10 - it would return the comment if you would use LIKE '%1%').

And even for a high traffic site; just using an index on commentId would make this a fast operation.

So go for the first option.

If you really doubt the speed of the first option, you could create a "cache" field in the comments table in which you count the amount of likes, so you don't have to perform a subquery to select the like count.

Comment: Thanks, so I'll do it like you said.